# DataTables Next button not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, datatables

I have a DataTable being initialized in a HTML web page, rendered piecewise by ajax calls to a Django backend.

Everything is working great, however, the [Next] and [Last] datatable buttons are not working. Pagination works fine, Prev and First also work fine.

DataTable code:

```
var object_table = $('#object_table').DataTable( {
     "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<ip>',
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "iOverlayFade": 100,    
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": '/objects/object_list/',
     "deferRender": true
     "aoColumnDefs": [ { "aTargets": [ 0 ], "sWidth": "1%",
                        "searchable":false, "orderable":false, } 
                    ],
"columns": function ( row, data, index ) {... }] 
});
```

And this is what the code looks like as it's passed from django on the datatables ajax call

```
def dt_object_list_loader:
    r_sequence = int(request.GET.get('draw', 0))
    r_length = int(request.GET.get('length', 10))
    r_start = int(request.GET.get('start', 0))
    objects = djangomodel.objects.filter(...) 
    result_list = [objects[r_start:r_start + r_length]
    response_data = {}
    response_data['recordsTotal'] = len(result_list)
    response_data['draw'] = int(request.GET.get('draw', 0))
    response_data['data'] = result_list


    return HttpResponse(jsonpickle.encode(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

Pagination works fine, and everything loads without error. But 'next/last' are blurred out, and when I click them, django fires the error:

```
Internal Server Error: /home/task_list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
r_start = int(request.GET.get('start', 0))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaN'
```

DataTables also fires a cryptic Error 7 (general ajax error) when the python error throws (this doesn't provide anything aside from what table the error occurred in.

Okay great, so I know when next or last is clicked, the r_start value provided from the datatables API is NaN. I could normally code around this by just setting the range manually, but I have no way of knowing from django which button was clicked (range for last or range for next) without doing some inane jquery.

This datatable is copied almost exactly from another part of my program and it works fine, I just changed some of the python code to spit out a different object list...so I'm pretty confused as to why this is busting.

I guess my question is, how can I make datatables send a more useful value on 'next' aside from just passing NaN and why are the next/last buttons blurred out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return `recordsFiltered` parameter in addition to `recordsTotal`.

```
response_data['recordsTotal'] = objects.count()
response_data['recordsFiltered'] = objects.count()
```

Since you're not performing search `recordsFiltered` parameter value should be equal to `recordsTotal`.

Comment: I actually had this line of code, but it was commented out. 

However, what did make this work was using the total length of all possible results, not just the result_list (which only contains a chunk of the entire queryset).

So In this example, I used response_data['recordsFiltered'] = objects.count()

And this worked. So this answer is mostly correct, if you could change it to objects.count() I can accept it.

Comment: @rob, I don't know Python but based on your description I figured out that `recordsFiltered` was missing.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a few hours of headaches!

Answer (score 1):

Gryocode's answer was mostly correct.

I had commented out 
response_data['recordsFiltered'] = len(result_list)

But when uncommented, this still didn't work.

I fixed this by setting

```
response_data['recordsFiltered'] = objects.count()
```

Unless search terms were provided, in which case I returned the length of the filtered objects queryset.